# How could I add combox and other items in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create an UI which allows me to select entries from one list box and add it to another listbox at the run time. Now, the listbox1 may contain combo box and checkbox as the items. 
  For example, if I add a combo box labelled Quarter with values "Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4" as an item in listbox1 and select the entry Q1 in it, and click on the "Add" button, it should be added to listbox2. Vice versa should also be possible. This should be possible at the run time. How could I add combo box and checkbox as an item to the listbox? Also, please suggest if for the add-remove buttons, the code I've is correct.

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
    {
        ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var item in sourceItems)
        {
            destination.Items.Add(item);
        }
        while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveListBoxItems(listBox1, listBox2);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveListBoxItems(listBox2, listBox1);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you properly format your question, and post some code. Otherwise you'll get downvotes and probably get your question closed.

Comment: Do you accept WPF-based solutions? you could integrate that in your existing winforms app using an `ElementHost`.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. But I've no clue on how to achieve that. Could you suggest a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a WPF solution to your need. I am posting it because you told me it could be useful for you. It largely surpasses anything you can ever hope to achieve in winforms, which is a very limited and outdated technology.

This is how it looks in my screen:

[image]

I am using some simple ViewModels to represent the data:

ListItemViewModel (the "base" one):

```
 public class ListItemViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _displayName;
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return _displayName; }
            set
            {
                _displayName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
```

BoolListItemViewModel (for CheckBoxes):

```
public class BoolListItemViewModel: ListItemViewModel
{
    private bool _value;
    public bool Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Value);
        }
    }
}
```

SelectableListItemViewModel (for ComboBoxes):

```
public class SelectableListItemViewModel: ListItemViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> _itemsSource;
    public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return _itemsSource ?? (_itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel>()); }
    }

    private ListItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ListItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the "Main" ViewModel, which holds the 2 lists and the `Commands` (the Button actions)

```
 public class ListBoxSampleViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> _leftItems;
        public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> LeftItems
        {
            get { return _leftItems ?? (_leftItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel>()); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> _rightItems;
        public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> RightItems
        {
            get { return _rightItems ?? (_rightItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel>()); }
        }

        private DelegateCommand<ListItemViewModel> _moveToRightCommand;
        public DelegateCommand<ListItemViewModel> MoveToRightCommand
        {
            get { return _moveToRightCommand ?? (_moveToRightCommand = new DelegateCommand<ListItemViewModel>(MoveToRight)); }
        }

        private void MoveToRight(ListItemViewModel item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                LeftItems.Remove(item);
                RightItems.Add(item);    
            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand<ListItemViewModel> _moveToLeftCommand;
        public DelegateCommand<ListItemViewModel> MoveToLeftCommand
        {
            get { return _moveToLeftCommand ?? (_moveToLeftCommand = new DelegateCommand<ListItemViewModel>(MoveToLeft)); }
        }

        private void MoveToLeft(ListItemViewModel item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                RightItems.Remove(item);
                LeftItems.Add(item);    
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the entire XAML for the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window14"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="Window14" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ListItemViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BoolListItemViewModel}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayName}" IsChecked="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectableListItemViewModel}">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LeftItems}"
                 x:Name="LeftList"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Move to Right" 
                    Command="{Binding MoveToRightCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=LeftList}"/>
            <Button Content="Move to Left" 
                    Command="{Binding MoveToLeftCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=RightList}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RightItems}"
                 Grid.Column="2" x:Name="RightList"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and finally, this is the Window Code-behind, which only initializes the ViewModel with some items:

```
   public partial class Window14 : Window
    {
        public Window14()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ListBoxSampleViewModel()
                              {
                                  LeftItems =
                                      {
                                          new ListItemViewModel(){DisplayName = "Item1"},
                                          new BoolListItemViewModel() {DisplayName = "Check Item 2", Value = true},
                                          new SelectableListItemViewModel()
                                              {
                                                  ItemsSource =
                                                      {
                                                          new ListItemViewModel() {DisplayName = "Combo Item 1"},
                                                          new BoolListItemViewModel() {DisplayName = "Check inside Combo"},
                                                          new SelectableListItemViewModel()
                                                              {
                                                                  ItemsSource =
                                                                      {
                                                                          new ListItemViewModel() {DisplayName = "Wow, this is awesome"},
                                                                          new BoolListItemViewModel() {DisplayName = "Another CheckBox"}
                                                                      }
                                                              }
                                                      }
                                              }
                                      }
                              };
        }
    }
```

At first glance, this might seem like a LOT of code... but if you take 2 seconds to analyze it... Its just "simple, simple properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's how you program in WPF.

I'm talking about a completely different paradigm from what you might be used to in winforms, but it's really worth the effort of learning it. Notice that nowhere in my code I am interacting with UI elements. I just create the `ViewModel` structure and let the `WPF Binding System` to take care of generating the UI for me, using the provided `DataTemplates`.

I'm using the `ViewModelBase` from [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) and the `DelegateCommand` from [WPFTutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html). You can copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself (you will also need these 2 classes from the links above)

If you need to integrate this in an existing winforms application, you will need the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)